# Update multiple record with single query in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an invoice in PHP where multiple products are inserted at once into one table and there grand total goes to another table. I am trying to UPDATE the invoice in MYSQL and PHP. When I press the submit button, the multiple records data from the form goes to the update.php but the query does not run.

database.php

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','invoice');
if (!$connect){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

edit_invoice.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<style>
    table,tr,td,th { border: 1px black solid;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="list_invoice.php">Back to Invoice List</a><br><br>
<?php
include('database.php');

$invoice_number = $_GET['invoice_number'];

$sql = "SELECT * from invoice where invoice_number = '$invoice_number' ";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
$fetch = $query->fetch_assoc();
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="update_invoice.php">
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Width</th>
    <th>Height</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
<?php

$sql2 = "SELECT * from invoice_order where invoice_number = '$invoice_number' ";
$query2 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);

if ($query2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

$srno = 1;
$count = $query2->num_rows;
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    while($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
  <tbody id="product_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="product[]" value="<?php echo $row["product"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $row["quantity"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="width[]" value="<?php echo $row["width"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="height[]" value="<?php echo $row["height"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $row["total"]; ?>" class="totalPrice" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="X" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<?php
    }
}
} else {
    echo "No Record Found";
}
?>

<input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Row" onclick="add_fields();">

<span>Invoice Date:<input type="date" value="<?php echo $fetch["invoice_date"]; ?>" name="invoice_date"></span>
<span>Invoice #:<input type="text" name="invoice_number" value="<?php echo $fetch["invoice_number"]; ?>" readonly></span>

<span>Select Customer:
  <select name="to_user" class="form-control">
    <option><?php echo $fetch["customer_id"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    include('database.php');
      $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * From customer");
      $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo "<option value='". $row['customer_id'] ."'>" .$row['customer_id'] ." - " .$row['customer_name'] ."</option>" ;
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</span>

</table>
<span>Grand Total<input type="text" name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal" value="<?php echo $fetch["grandtotal"]; ?>" readonly></span><br><br>
<span>Paid Amount<input type="text" name="paid" id="paid" value="<?php echo $fetch["paid"]; ?>"></span><br><br>
<span>Balance<input type="text" name="balance" id="balance" value="<?php echo $fetch["balance"]; ?>" readonly></span><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

<script>
const table = document.getElementById('product_table');
table.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
  const tr = target.closest('tr');
  const [product, price, quantity, width, height, total] = tr.querySelectorAll('input');

  var size = width.value * height.value;
  var rate = price.value * quantity.value;

  if (size != "") {
    total.value = size * rate;
  }else{
    total.value = rate; 
  }
  totalPrice();
});

function add_fields() {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML =
    '<td><input type="text" name="product[]"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="price[]"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="width[]" value="0"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="height[]" value="0"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="total[]"  class="totalPrice" readonly></td>' +
    '<td><input type="button" value="X" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>';

  table.appendChild(row);
}

function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  totalPrice();
}

function totalPrice() {
  var grandtotal = 0;
  var paid = 0;
  $(".totalPrice").each(function() {
    grandtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    paid = grandtotal;
  });
  $("#grandtotal").val(grandtotal);
  $("#paid").val(paid);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#paid').on('input', function() {
    grandtotal = $("#grandtotal").val();
    paid = $("#paid").val();
    balance = parseFloat(grandtotal) - parseFloat(paid);
    $("#balance").val(balance);
  })
});


</script>
</html>
```

Update_invoice.php

```
<?php

    include('database.php');

    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

        $product  = $_POST['product'];
        $price    = $_POST['price'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $width    = $_POST['width'];
        $height   = $_POST['height'];
        $total    = $_POST['total'];

        $customer_id    = $_POST['to_user'];
        $invoice_date   = $_POST['invoice_date'];
        $invoice_number = $_POST['invoice_number'];
        $grandtotal     = $_POST['grandtotal'];
        $paid           = $_POST['paid'];
        $balance        = $_POST['balance'];
        $amount_status  = "";

        if ($grandtotal == $paid) {
            $amount_status = "Paid";
        } elseif ($grandtotal == $balance) {
            $amount_status = "Due";
        } else {
            $amount_status = "Partial";
        }

        // Start of Updating data to invoice_order table
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['total']); $i++) {
            if ($i <> count($_POST['total'])) {

                $sql = "UPDATE invoice_order SET invoice_number = '$invoice_number' , product = '$_POST['product'][$i]', price = '$_POST['price'][$i]' , quantity = '$_POST['quantity'][$i]', width = '$_POST['width'][$i]' , height = '$_POST['height'][$i]' , total = '$_POST['total'][$i]' WHERE invoice_number='$invoice_number' ";

                $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                if ($query) {
                    header('location: list_invoice.php');
                } else {
                    echo "Unable to enter records in invoice_order table";
                }
            }
        }
        // End of updating data to invoice_order table

        // Start of updating data to invoice table
        $sql2 = "UPDATE invoice SET customer_id = '$customer_id', grandtotal = '$grandtotal', invoice_number = '$invoice_number', invoice_date = '$invoice_date', paid = '$paid', balance = '$balance', amount_status = '$amount_status' WHERE invoice_number='$invoice_number' ";

        $query2 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);
        if ($query2) {
            header('location: list_invoice.php');
        } else {
            echo "Unable to enter record in invoice table";
        }
        // End of updating data to invoice table
    }

?>
```

Comment: according to the comment `// Start of Adding data to invoice_order table` I'd expect the statement to be an `insert into ...` rather than and `update...` - that aside I think when it comes to using variables ( such as `$_POST['price'][$i]` ) within a quoted SQL statement ( incidentally making it vulnerable to SQL injection ), you need to use curly braces around the variables... like `{$_POST['price'][$i]}` etc ~ you would be better using `prepared statements`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using is not the preferred way of doing the job. Use mysql prepare statement. This will make the code clean, easy to read and secured. Here is the link you can refer [Mysql Prepared Statement in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I am still under confusion. Can you please give me a proper code solution?

Comment: @ZubairAhmad please attach the sql and the database.php content, so i can rewrite the code.